# How can I have Google Cloud Security Scanner log into my app?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I ran  Google Cloud Security Scanner against my Google App Engine app. I asked it to authenticate against a "Non-Google Account" -- in other words, user-name/password fields in my webapp. However, I get back the message "Could not sign in using the provided username and password" each time.

(I tried it several times, specifying different user-agents and credentials and against two variants of my login page; and of course confirming that the credentials work when typed in manually. I have the necessary Editor-level  permissions on the Google Cloud project.)

What do I need to do to get the Scanner to authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/security-scanner/using-the-scanner#creating_a_scan) say about Non-Google account authentication:

> Note that support for login forms is still in development, and may not
>   work out-of-the-box with your system. If you have confirmed your test
>   account is able to login manually, but not in Cloud Security Scanner,
>   use the feedback option within the tools to request support.

One possible workaround is to create a simplified alternative login form for the purposes of using the scanner if it's unable to work with the current one.

Comment: Thank you. The entire page, including the login form, is built in Ajax, and so the form is not present when the Scanner's browser first requests it. The Scanner's browser would have to wait a moment for the Ajax to build the login form. 

This may be the source of the problem.

Comment: 3 years have passed, and Cloud Security Scanner is now available for GKE and GCE applications. Is there any public update on a timeline for improved support of form-based login?